# Why do arrays of numbers, more data sort faster than arrays of objects, fewer data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

For my application in node.js I must sort elements of an array in descending order based on some numeric value (i.e. a numeric rank). Since my application is performance-critical, I decided to build my data structure so that sorting is optimized. I hypothesized that the fewer data contained per element in my array, the faster the sorts will be. To test my hypothesis, I ran the following on three different arrays of length 10000:

> **EDIT**: Guys, it seems as though there was something flawed with my original testing. The first test takes significantly longer than the ones that follow. As such, I have modified my test code to have a 'buffer' sort before the actual sorts. Furthermore, I rotated the order of my tests for a fixed number of trials to reduce any bias that might result from the ordering of the tests themselves. I've modified the results accordingly.

Full source here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/youngrrrr/js-array-sort-bench-test/master/arraySortTest.js

```
var buffer = [781197, ... ];
var sparseArray = [781197, ... ];
var sparseArray2 = [{'a' : 781197}, ...];
var denseArray = [{'a' : 781197, 'b': ['r', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'm'] }, ...];

/* buffer : for some reason, the first test always takes significantly longer than the others. I've added this to try to remove whatever bias there was before... */
console.time('buffer');
random.sort(compareSparse);
console.timeEnd('buffer');
console.log(buffer[0]); // prints "58"


/* sparseArray : an array whose elements are numbers */
console.time('sparse');
sparseArray.sort(compareSparse);
console.timeEnd('sparse');
console.log(sparseArray[0]); // prints "58"

/* sparseArray2 (not an accurate name, just got lazy) :
   an array whose elements are objects with a single key-value pair mapping
   an arbitrary name 'a' to a number (which we sort on) */
console.time('sparse2');
sparseArray2.sort(compareDense);
console.timeEnd('sparse2');
console.log(sparseArray2[0]); // prints "{ a: 58 }"

/* denseArray : an array whose elements are objects with two key-value
   pairs mapping an arbitrary key 'a' to a number (which we sort on) and
   another arbitrary key 'b' to an array (which is just supposed to be 
   extra data for the purpose of my hypothesis) */
console.time('dense');
denseArray.sort(compareDense);
console.timeEnd('dense');
console.log(denseArray[0]); // prints "{ a: 58, b: [ 'r', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'm' ] }"

function compareSparse(a, b) {
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a > b) {
        return 1;   }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function compareDense(a, b) {
    if (a.a < b.a) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a.a > b.a) {
            return 1;   }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

> **Old test:**

<s>After 25 trials (I know, small sample size but I did this all manually) I got the following times for average sort time:</s>

- **sparseArray**: (24 + 23 + 21 + 23 + 21 + 22 + 22 + 22 + 22 + 22 + 21 + 20 + 22 + 24 + 24 + 21 + 22 + 22 + 25 + 23 + 24 + 23 + 21 + 21 + 23) / 25 = **22.32ms**
- **sparseArray2**: (4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 4 + 6 + 5 + 5 + 4 + 5 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 4 + 5 + 4 + 4 + 5) / 25 = **4.56ms**
- **denseArray**: (5 + 5 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 6 + 5 + 5 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 6 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 4) / 25 = **4.88ms**

> **New test:**

After 25 trials (I know, small sample size but I did this all manually) I got the following times for average sort time:

- **sparseArray**: (4+4+4+4+3+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+3+4+4)/15 = **3.867ms**
- **sparseArray2**: (4+4+4+6+5+4+4+4+4+5+5+4+5+5+5)/15 = **4.533ms**
- **denseArray**: (4+4+4+5+5+4+4+4+4+5+5+4+5+5+5)/15 = **4.466ms**

So I've come to the following conclusions:

- Arrays of numbers sort faster than arrays of objects whose values are numbers. This makes sense intuitively.
- For some reason, and paradoxically so, more data in a particular element results in faster sorting than less data (as evidenced by sparseArray2 vs denseArray runtimes).

What I want to know is:

- Are these conclusions backed by any documentation/something other than my testing? That is, did I reach the correct conclusions?
- And why? Why do arrays of numbers sort faster than arrays of objects (makes sense intuitively, but what's the explanation behind this, if any)? Not only this, but why do arrays containing **MORE** data seem to sort faster than those containing *less* data?

And note, I'm not married to these conclusions or anything. The sample size is small and my testing has proven to be flawed before, so my results may very well just be the result of bad testing. Also, there seem to be various factors that I have no awareness about that could be affecting the results (as Ryan O'Hara pointed out in my earlier post). The point of this post is to discover any fact-based explanation for sorting behavior in Javascript.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Reorder the tests and you’ll get pretty significantly different answers – it might be best to iterate these.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara oh wow that's embarrassing... wonder what's going on...

Comment: @RyanO'Hara - fixed... and now I still have just as many questions...

Comment: As of last time I checked (about a month ago) V8 does not detect pure functions and inline them, so probably the most performant method would be one that does not use the native sort at all ...anyway I still think it's probably premature optimization :)

Comment: That `console.time` has too low precision. Better use `performance.now`. And create the data randomly. Then them all seem to take similar amounts of time, at least on Firefox.

Comment: _why do arrays containing MORE data seem to sort faster than those containing less data?_ Did you try it on multiple array sizes? Or by more data do you mean only larger objects, but same array length?

Comment: @FabioBeltramini right, but in this case I do not use the native sort for any of my test arrays.

Comment: @Oriol the point of this post wasn't so much the actual tests themselves. I agree that it's not perfect. The point was to see if there was any existing documentation that could explain behavior for sorting in Javascript.

Comment: @hege_hegedus by more data, I just mean larger objects, same array length

Comment: By "native sort" I meant the `[].sort` method because you necessarily have to invoke a function many times. It might be faster using a loop (again, given the present compiler optimizations, it the future that may reverse)

Comment: @FabioBeltramini oh I see. So you're saying the most current, efficient way to sort would be by implementing my own loop/sorting function (e.g. mergesort) instead of using the builtin sort method? Also, do you have a source for your previous comment?

Comment: Technically it's worth mentioning there is no "javascript" sorting performance. Different implementations will perform differently because the ECMAScript standard only specifies the result of the operation and not how to do it. In fact, this means that the performance can change from version to version of a given implementation and still adhere to the standard

Comment: @FabioBeltramini I'm starting to think I'm in way over my head.... It really seems the differences, like you say, might be trivial. I will try seeing how a particular implementation fares and revisit this question if further optimizations become necessary. Thanks for your input though, I appreciate it.

Comment: I don't have it on hand, but I know it was explicitly stated by a developer as current as of a couple months ago. Just google for pure function inlining...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are these conclusions backed by any documentation/something other than
>   my testing? That is, did I reach the correct conclusions?

The specifics of how `.sort()` is implemented is not required by any specification, therefore the performance aspects of `.sort()` are only to be discovered via performance testing interesting data sets in browsers or JS implementations of interest.  Pretty much all performance questions are best answered with testing in the specific circumstances that matter to you.  Generalizations outside of that can easily be misleading or wrong and do not necessarily apply to all configurations.

> And why? Why do arrays of numbers sort faster than arrays of objects
>   (makes sense intuitively, but what's the explanation behind this, if
>   any)? Not only this, but why do arrays containing MORE data seem to
>   sort faster than those containing less data?

The performance of a given sort with a custom comparison function is going to be governed by the following items:

1. The length of the array.  A longer array will require more sort comparisons.
2. The smarts of the internal sort algorithm to reduce the number of sort comparisons as small as possible
3. The performance of the custom sort function (how long it takes to execute a given sort comparison).

So, if you hold the custom sort function and the `.sort()` implementation you're using constant and the data in the array constant, then a longer array will take longer to sort.

But, if you change both 1. and 3. above (one in a favorable direction and one in a less favorable direction) as you are doing when you go from sorting an array of numbers to sorting an array of objects by a specific property value, then the delta in speed will dependent upon whether the net change is positive or negative which depends upon several things which are hard to predict outside of a very specific implementation and data set and a lot of testing (in other words, it could go either way).

For some test info on sorting an array of numbers vs. sorting a property from an array of objects, see http://jsperf.com/sort-value-vs-property.  To no surprise, it is slightly faster to sort the array of numbers though not by a lot.

Comment: Nice discussion! One note though: all of the test arrays are the same length: 10,000 elements each. And since the sort keys appear to be the same in each of the arrays, they should all result in the same number of calls to the sort function - indeed, the same *sequence* of calls and parameter values. One obvious difference between the sort functions is that one of them does a bit more work because it's using property references instead of direct numeric values.

Comment: @MichaelGeary - That is the point - the "scientific method".  I'm trying to compare equal length arrays of values and objects to see which is actually faster.  Hold one variable constant while you change the other in order to test one thing at a time.  If you compare two arrays of different length with different contents, then the results don't tell you anything useful because you don't know which change caused the difference in outcome.  Yes, the result is as you would expect it to be, but the test tells you that the difference is not very much even for a fairly long array.

Comment: Here's the specific error I was referring to: "if you change both 1. and 3. above (one in a favorable direction and one in a less favorable direction) as you are doing when you go from sorting an array of numbers to sorting an array of objects by a specific property value" Only your point 3 is changing between the sort examples; point 1 (the length of the array) is the same in all of them.

Comment: @MichaelGeary - if you read my answer, I'm explaining that you can't draw any reasonable testing conclusion by changing two things at once.  When it shows up slower or faster, you won't know why.  You have to change one thing at a time and measure.  We all know that a longer array will be slower to sort if everything else is held equal.  So, the only remaining question is how much difference there is between sorting values vs. properties.   That's what I showed.  If you want to change two things, then your result is only meaningful for one specific set of data which the OP did not offer.

Comment: @MichaelGeary - You can't draw any general conclusion if you test changing two things at once - only a specific conclusion for that exact set of data.

Comment: Look, we agree on all that. I'm just trying to let you know that your answer has a minor factual mistake in it: you said the OP was changing both the array length and the comparison function (your points 1 and 3). Only point 3 changed between tests. Point 1 never changes - the array length is the same in all the tests. This would be super easy for you to fix with a little copyedit, and then we'll all be happy. :-)

Comment: @MichaelGeary - You lost me there.  The OP talks about comparing arrays of different lengths where the longer one has different data, but is faster.  What minor copy edit you would suggest?  You've lost me for what you think needs to be corrected.

Comment: Hang in there with me, my friend, and we will get this *sorted* out. ;-) From OP's question: "I ran the following on three different arrays *of length 10000*" (emphasis added). And indeed, if you check `.length` of each array in the test file they are all 10000. Do my comments make more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it has to do with the way the sorting works in javascript. Numbers [are converted to strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) before sorting if the comparison function is not supplied, action that takes some time.

Comment: This is with the default comparison function. OP uses a custom one.

Comment: I think that's a fair point (and something I will definitely keep in mind!) but as someone else has pointed out, this doesn't apply due to the custom comparison function I use.